# Version selection buttons are unclear

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-editor, user-experience

When adding documentation, the editor has a set of buttons that correspond to the version(s) that the feature exists in. As they stand, the buttons don't clearly show whether or not they're activated.

[image: Buttons]

Was this topic added in 2.0 or removed after 1.9?

The editor background and default state of the buttons is the light grey. I had it in my head they defaulted to off and by selecting them, they changed color and became active. In fact, this is backwards of what happens.

It would be great to get either some color or more clear UX to indicate which the active versions are. Or, a live preview in the editor (right now, despite having only half the buttons clicked, the tag says `All Versions` next to my topic name). This appears to be the only editor function that doesn't live update.

Thanks!

Comment: Agree, the UI is _too flat_ here.

Comment: …or use the text-based format like inline versions.

Comment: @bwoebi But... ironically removing colors is trendy! Even Microsoft does it, their Metrosexual UI only looks like Windows 98 as a nihilistic commentary of our ennui culture. Deep down, all buttons are equal.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Trends are fine… But only tertiary behind looking good and, in particular, usability. [Too many designers get that wrong though :x]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've updated the style to make it more clear which versions are selected:

[image: So orange!]