# What should we do about the endless old OpenGL API questions that clutter search when looking for modern OpenGL core profile API solutions?

Tags: discussion

One problem Stack Overflow has had with respect to OpenGL is that, while I *can* often find the answer to what I want, I'm forced to wade through a ton of irrelevant answers/questions that deal with the old OpenGL API.

Now these answers and questions *should still stay*. There are many people stuck on older APIs, however I'm using 3.3+ core, and I don't have access and don't care to use the old API.

Here are some examples I've been shown first while searching for things just relating to OpenGL which have gotten in the way of proper results:

- *[Opengl drawing a 2d overlay on a 3d scene problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280185/opengl-drawing-a-2d-overlay-on-a-3d-scene-problem)*
- *[VBO - Drawing multiple elements with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222257/vbo-drawing-multiple-elements-with-different-colors?rq=1)*
- *[Can I use a grayscale image with the OpenGL glTexImage2D function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680125/can-i-use-a-grayscale-image-with-the-opengl-glteximage2d-function)*
- *[How to use glOrtho() in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571402/how-to-use-glortho-in-opengl)*
- *[OpenGL Error underflow turns into overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4433636/2036035)*
- *[How to use alpha transparency in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617370/how-to-use-alpha-transparency-in-opengl)*

Each of these reference immediate modes obviously can't use this. It often happens that I will try to find "how to do X transform" or something in OpenGL, and be brought to a question using immediate mode primitives which have all since been removed from OpenGL core. Check out what happens when you look up "enable transparency OpenGL", for me at least I get virtually all old API questions/answers.

[image]

Or look at what happens when you search "grayscale OpenGL texture":

[image]

One thing you'll notice about most of these questions is that most happened before 2010, when modern OpenGL wasn't really an option.

Searching OpenGL core, or 3.3+ removes *valid* searches as most questions don't put core or the version number in the title or tags. They just put OpenGL. In fact there isn't a way to really specify something as *modern* OpenGL, OpenGL 3.0 doesn't mean that it's modern and misses key features after the 3.3 core feature set, and there are still many people on OpenGL 3.0 using compatibility features.  you could have a "core" tag but then would you need that for each version?  OpenGL core means different things for different versions. Even if you managed this, this would require *new* questions to be tagged as core, when new people, or even people who've been here a while and don't realize that the tag exists will probably just default to OpenGL anyway not solving the issue.

Then there is the issue that some one could be using compatibility for one small thing (`GL_LUMINANCE` for example), but have an answer to the question that only uses core features, and because so many questions don't specify the version and profile type, answers come from *both* places.

But the existence of old questions that don't specify a profile type or version of OpenGL that ask a question, and then only get old API answers and only accept old API questions would seem hint that at least some of these questions should be explicitly marked *compatibility* or *old API* or something that isn't just "OpenGL" because of how vague that tag is now.

In fact I'd argue that a plain OpenGL tag ought to be re-evaluated because of how different the new core profile is from the old API. A question about the old API is just not relevant to me. But there just doesn't seem to be a way to tag to differentiate old API questions from new API questions.

**Is there anything I can actually do when I see a question I recognize as an "old API" question to make sure others aren't hit with looking at the same old API questions?**

Comment: "*Then there is the issue that some one could be using compatibility for one small thing (GL_LUMINANCE for example)*" FYI: that's what [texture swizzle masks](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Swizzle) are for.

Comment: "*how to do X transform*" It should be noted that most questions of this form, from a "modern OpenGL" perspective, are not OpenGL questions anymore. OpenGL as an API is no longer part of transformation.

Comment: @NicolBolas yeah I know on the `GL_LUMINANCE` but I was just mentioning it as a pattern I've seen where people will use compatibility for just that feature alone, but then use core for everything else.  For the second part, what will often happen is that I'm actually searching for glm + opengl stuff but it returns opengl immediate mode junk.

Comment: @NicolBolas A more specific example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280185/opengl-drawing-a-2d-overlay-on-a-3d-scene-problem) where I had a very similar question to the title, but the old api style made it completely irrelevant to me

Comment: @NicolBolas  Actually another thing about that `GL_LUMINANCE` thing that further proves my point, I was looking to do grayscale output with opengl 3.3+ core, and almost switched to compatibility because all the answers I kept finding here pointed to using `GL_LUMINANCE` I think there was like one answer to a question that actually gave me the correct answer about swizzle masks (and it might have been yours actually :) ), but it was on another question.

Comment: [The top Google hit for "OpenGL Luminance Core Profile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173075/replacement-for-gl-luminance-alpha-in-core-profile).

Comment: @NicolBolas That is definitely not the search term I would have used, though, because I didn't even know what GL_LUMINANCE actually was at the time, it was only when I actually tried to use it that I realized it wasn't available in the core profile.  The issue wasn't finding a replacement for GL_LUMINANCE it was that I was being bombarded with old API junk in the first place.  In fact I hadn't seen that link until just now.  All this happened like a year ago any way, so it is actually possible that post didn't exist at that point, it was posted in 2017.

Comment: @NicolBolas [top stack overflow hit from google for "grayscale opengl texture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680125/can-i-use-a-grayscale-image-with-the-opengl-glteximage2d-function)

Comment: +1 for the freehand circles (and ... yeah, the question). I'd like to point at the [comment by user69513](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368920/what-to-do-about-the-endless-old-opengl-api-questions-that-clutter-search-when-l?cb=1#comment596839_368935) which may be worthwhile thinking about here. Do you think that this could solve the problem?

Comment: Are there not version-specific opengl tags? Maybe it's time to add some.

Comment: @TylerH there are and there aren't, there are opengl-3 tags and opengl-4 tags, but no opengl-2 tags nor opengl-1 tags, and all questions pretty much must have the opengl tag also, so at least two tags need to be taken up by just talking about the opengl version.  Additionally many opengl-3 and 4 questions don't actually have opengl-3 and opengl-4 tags, and many that do are compatibility and use non core features from their respective versions, making the answers not very relevant even with the tag.

Comment: @Marco13 Maybe it could solve the problem?  I'm just not sure how feasible it is.

Comment: @snb Well typically with version-specific tags, you include them *only if* your question is about version-specific features. In cases where the versions are rewrites or altogether incompatible with prior versions, you edit the non-version-specific tag to refer to the "old" versions and use version specific tags *only* moving forward. E.g. if 1 and 2 are old, and 3 or 4 are totally new, then [tag:opengl] should be described as such (OLD) with instructions to use the newer tag. In cases where people are using non-core features, they should use non-core tags (and the tag for their opengl version)

Comment: @snb See [tag:python] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap]; two extremely high-traffic tags that have already dealt with this issue.

Comment: This discussion is mostly about past, obsolete posts. What about future posts? Wouldn't it be a good idea to add a version tagging system for all future questions of this nature? SO could then have more control in who finds the post and only show the post to a query relevant to *that* version of whatever it is.

Comment: @www139 we've more or less been discussing that in the other answers comments, but this is another good option as well.

Comment: @TylerH: The reason I don't think that version tags would work for OpenGL is that there was only one clear-cut change (From non-core profile to core profile). All other versions (which means 3.1 to currently 4.6, or the last 8 years) are kind of additions to the previous versions. It is perfectly fine to use 3.3 things in a 4.6 context. This also means that it is hard to tag with the relevant version. And depending on the answers this might change.

Comment: Consider a question that contains code that is compatible with 3.3. Do you tag it with opengl-3? opengl3.3? opengl-4 because it still works there? Or with all version between 3.1 and 4.6? Now an answer gets added which uses DSA (which is only available in 4.5+): Do I now have to retag the question because the answer will only work with 4.5+? And this does not even cover the problem of OpenGL extensions (features that are added to one version and get approved into core in a later version). The problem is: The whole OpenGL version system is a mess.

Comment: @BDL so I guess all that's left is to switch to DirectX? :-)

Comment: Am I missing something? This whole meta post is about retagging and versioning stuff... but ultimately you're going to ask Google the question, or whatever search engine you like. note how Google highlights the keywords that were searched on; keywords in the indexed **content**, not in the tags. I don't know, but retagging is likely not going to change Google's mind as A) the content stays the same and B) you're still searching for something too generic, so even if search results could be better filtered you'd get less of them, not necessarily "newer" ones.

Comment: @snb I see the other comments mention that new API releases may not change enough to make a post relevant to only one version and the exclusion of all others. I.e., some API updates change almost nothing. I can understand how that might lead to confusion though readers probably would realize that the tagging system is kind of a guideline. It cannot be 100% accurate for every situation. A good way to implement the system: when a question is posted, if an API tag is used, add a required field for the version number as a select list.

Comment: @snb I think this post also bring to light a concern for obsolete code in general. Since SO has only existed for 10 years, even the oldest posts haven't quite hit the obsolete stage yet but obsolescence is inevitable even for programming languages. I've noticed issues with obsolete answers. Maybe, some day, posts older than 10 years might be hidden by default unless a peer review confirms the information is still current enough to be valuable.

Comment: @Gimby That's an important note. However, maybe the tagging system could postfix the title of the post so then the results in search engines clearly display the version number in the tagging system.

Comment: @Gimby The only reason google was used is because its still better than Stack Overflows search functionality, which frankly has never been good.  With proper tagging I would be able to use SOs search more effectively.

Comment: @Gimby also you are missing the comment discussion where google was used to show "look at how easy it is to use google to see new opengl questions" and I used the two google searches to show it is exactly the opposite.

Comment: @snb spamming multiple comments do not persuade me into believing that the site search will ever compete with Google for finding relevant information.

Answer (score 26):

I think that what you're running into here is a fundamental weakness in the StackOverflow categorization and labeling model. As I understand it, the tagging system largely exists in order to get unanswered questions in front of potential answerers (hopefully domain experts) with minimal noise (ie not showing it to people who can't answer). It works quite well for this; note that a single OpenGL tag is more than sufficient to receive an answer to a new question.

Since things are then (theoretically) nicely categorized, this also augments search and retrieval efforts by, for example, Google. In my opinion, this model works quite well for things that don't change over time, as well as for things which exhibit large scale changes all at once. Unfortunately, as noted by you search and retrieval begins to break down when large numbers of small changes occur over time, such as has happened with the OpenGL API.

You mention in a comment,

> the amount of work it takes to get a relevant answer just through SO is enough to actually cause significant problems in learning the material, so what is recommended to do about this?

I agree, and think it's worth noting that this is actually a fairly serious issue for anyone seeking to learn new material. Bear in mind that by definition, someone new to a subject doesn't yet know much about it. Not only do they not know the answer to *this particular question*, they also (most likely) don't have any idea about that new feature over there that could provide an alternative approach to their problem. Moreover, they're incredibly unlikely to recognize an (obviously, to an expert) obsolete or outdated approach. In fact, this is (usually) one of the key strengths of the StackOverflow model - the answerer is likely to be able to point out any misconceptions or make the questioner aware of newer, potentially relevant features (if the question is well written, at least).

You ask,

> Is there anything I can actually do when I see a question I recognize as an "old api" question to make sure others aren't hit with looking at the same old api questions?

An approach based on tagging is tempting, but as @NicolBolas says,

> And who decides where that difference is? ... Everyone has their own ideas of where "modern OpenGL" begins and ends.

As @BDL mentions, a tag for each separate version is unworkable due to the 5 tag limit. Moreover, any tag based solution is likely to be irrelevant as I also completely agree with @NicolBolas that,

> Even if we could agree on some standard, recategorizing a tag containing 30,000+ questions is just not practical.

The suggestion of providing (modernized) new answers to old questions would certainly do *something* to help, but it's simply not a satisfactory solution.

- It would likely take a long term sustained effort before things would change (from the perspective of someone searching).
- This is almost guaranteed to be a recurring issue for any similar API - a general, permanent solution sure would be nice.

So what can we do? Unfortunately, I think the answer is more or less nothing. This seems to me to be an inherent limitation of the current tagging model, and I don't see any easy solution to it that doesn't involve software changes on StackOverflow's part. For example, this could be addressed with enhanced "API" tags that enabled the specification of version *ranges*, and which could be independently applied to both questions and answers; this would effectively allow filtering. However, we simply don't have such a feature (and it seems to me unlikely that it will appear).

Comment: One of the few good ideas from the SO Documentation project was version range boxes/highlights. Shame those never made it back to Q&A.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom maybe we can use this question as evidence that such a feature would be useful for SO, for now I leave that to some one else though.

Comment: @jeffrey-bosboom Even with a version box, we could  only add a version to the question. But this doesn't solve the problem. The same question can have a pre 3.3 answer and 3.3+ answer.

Comment: @BDL By "box" I don't mean a text field, I mean like the "Note" or "Warming" highlighted sections you might see in a book.  In addition to marking a whole topic as relating to specific versions, you could bracket any text in an example body with horizontal rule-like things saying "Versions XXX-YYY" or "Version YYY onwards" etc.  Now that Documentation is dead, I can't show you what it rendered like, but [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328554/3614835) shows the syntax.

Comment: @BDL see example in this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329680/what-happens-if-documentation-applies-to-all-versions.  That's probably too subtle for Q&A, where readers are quickly scanning for the part of the answer that applies to them, but that's easily fixed by increasing the text size.

Comment: I'm envisioning a standard question tag, still in a rectangle at the bottom. But in addition to the current behavior (hover popup, info page, etc), include optional min & max version numbers. So ex the regular OpenGL tag, being for an API, would be changed into an API tag by the community. Then when tagging `[OpenGL]` is valid, but also (something like) `[OpenGL<3.0>]` (exact), `[OpenGL<3.0-4.3>]` (range), `[OpenGL<-4.3>]` (less), and `[OpenGL<3.0->]` (greater). This is general for all APIs, and facilitates filtering. Bonus points if API tags can be applied independently to answers as well...

Comment: @user69513 That tag version thing was roughly what popped into my mind after reading the question. It's certainly far from trivial to implement, but IIRC, they did something similar for the SO Documentation (so maybe they could re-use some of the Documentation code, at least). I could imagine that this was already proposed somewhere here at meta (I didn't yet do a search), but if not, it would be great to suggest this as a feature request.

Comment: @jeffrey-bosboom Sorry that I didn't state that well enough. What I wanted to say is that this whole versioning thing would only make sense when it is applied on a per-answer bases, not per-question. Since you are usually googling a question and not an answers, I'm not so sure if it would really improve the search experiences.

Comment: @user69513 Something like [this per-topic version selector](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334477/3614835) popping up on hover?

Answer (score 15):

> But there just doesn't seem to be a way to tag to differentiate old api questions from new api questions.

And who decides where that difference is? Indeed, you provided an example right here: `GL_LUMINANCE` and a few other compatibility features are sometimes used by code that is predominantly "new API". But to some, that would be a disqualification from using that classification system.

Everyone has their own ideas of where "modern OpenGL" begins and ends. To me, if you're still using the `glVertexAttrib*Pointer` or `glTexImage*` functions, you're not really using *modern* OpenGL. And eventually, that will be, "if you're not using direct state access functions, you're not really using modern OpenGL".

"Modern" changes with time. I picked those two because OpenGL ES 3.1 has the newer APIs for that functionality (separate attrib format and texture storage), so there are few excuses for acting like those APIs don't exist/aren't superior in every way.

And yet for some people, "modern" means maximum platform compatibility. Since OpenGL implementations greater than 4.1 will *never* be provided on Mac OS, they consider "modern OpenGL" to end with 4.1. Obviously, I disagree, but their reasoning is still sound.

Even if we could agree on some standard, recategorizing a tag containing 30,000+ questions is just not practical.

The only effective solution is to post more answers that use what you feel are "modern OpenGL" solutions. If you see a question that could have a modern OpenGL solution that's different from the old stuff (assuming the question isn't specific to old stuff), then provide one.

Comment: I can define exactly what I want though, Opengl 3.3+ core. If it isn't in the core, I don't care. But there currently isn't even a tag to qualify core, let alone after a certain feature point, and way too much old stuff is showing up for modern searches for opengl. I think marking posts as "opengl-compatibility" might also help, or forcing opengl to specify api version in tag because of the massive differences. The issue right now is that it is often hard to get proper results with simple searches encouraging people to use compatibility features because they can't find the right answers.

Comment: @snb: Which questions do you retag? Consider your "greyscale" question. That code is perfectly valid in 3.3+ core code, so an answer that uses 3.3+ core is perfectly valid. There aren't any such answers on it, but there *could be*. Why would it need to be retagged? Again, the problem would be better solved by providing 3.3+ answers, not by retagging questions just because you don't want to see them.

Comment: If I knew *what* to do about this problem I wouldn't have asked meta, I just know there is a serious issue with the visibility of core profile questions and answers.  I think maybe we add opengl-1 and opengl-2 tags, and/or we could do opengl-3-core and opengl-4-core, or opengl-3-compatibility and opengl-4-compatibility (but not both core and compatibility), and set out to remove the opengl tag (since it isn't nearly specific enough) at some point in the far future.  No need for 3.3 specifically, answers/questions can specify if they are talking about specific sub-versions.

Comment: @snb: We already have tags for opengl-3 and opengl-4. We don't need specific ones for core and compatibility.

Comment: ok, what about opengl-2 and opengl-1 tags?  Also why not have something to differentiate core and compatibility?

Comment: The major problem I see with tagging such things is that a question can only have 5 tags. Most of the time two are already used for [opengl] and the language in which they are working. How would I now tag a question that is good for everything between 3.3 core and 4.5 core, but not afterwards because it doesn't use DSA? I'm also missing a definition of when one would be allowed to use a opengl version tag. Whenever the code works in that version? Whenever the code is optimally written for that version? What about questions that have multiple answers where one uses DSA, the other one doesn't?

Comment: @BDL Yeah tagging may not be the best solution, but IMO the amount of work it takes to get a relevant answer just through SO is enough to actually cause significant problems in learning the material, so what is recommended to do about this?  It may be enough to simply mark questions only opengl 2.x features as opengl-2 though, as there currently isn't an opengl-2 tag IIRC (same with opengl-1.x).  That way one could ignore opengl-2 tags.  Though that still doesn't seem entirely feasible either, and It doesn't help that opengl version seem sort of arbitrary

Comment: *"The only effective solution is to post more answers that use what you feel are "modern OpenGL" solutions."* - and also to comment on old answers, pointing out that while they were once the best approach, a new approach exists that is superior for [reasons] and described in [other answer]. Such comments - assuming that they're technically sound - are valuable to future readers who might otherwise just assume that the currently-top-voted answer must be the best solution.

Comment: Why *never*? Just because Metal?

Comment: I would also ask you to consider all the different flavors of OpenGL.  WebGL is "modern" but only has access to `glTexImage*` functions.  However, many of the broader OpenGL version questions are still applicable and might be missed if we say we only want a particular version.  Also, what about using WebGL 2 spec?  What do we lose?  What do we gain?  I am appreciating this whole post as it is an interesting question.

Comment: @zero298: The OpenGL community is already quite good at separating (desktop-)opengl, opengl-es and webgl questions. There shouldn't be many questions that have more than one of these tags. Also the tag wiki mentions that [tag:opengl] is only for desktop opengl.

Comment: @zero298 While I've had tons of issues with old opengl api questions/answers getting in the way of finding new openglapi answers, I've never had issue with WebGL questions and answers getting in the way.  Not to mention webgl versions are a lot more clear and cut than opengl versions.

Comment: @JaredSmith: "*Just because Metal?*" Well yes. Imagine Microsoft with Direct3D. They ditched improving OpenGL support past 1.1 because they wanted D3D to work out. GL works on Windows because of the way Microsoft choose to implement GL; they provided a direct connection between the GL and the implementation, thus allowing core features to be exposed by loading function pointers. MacOS has no such direct connection; Apple controls the interface between GL and the implementation. So GL exposes exactly and only what Apple *allows* it to expose.

Comment: @JaredSmith: never seems to fit since apple deprecated OpenGL in macOS 10.14. https://developer.apple.com/macos/whats-new/

Answer (score 1):

> But there just doesn't seem to be a way to tag to differentiate old api questions from new api questions.

Maybe filter question and answers by creation date. Define a date range that you think will most likely contain all interesting new api questions and ignore all questions and answers from before. That will increase the SNR and improve the situation a bit.

Using the creation date may not work well with questions or answers that got updated. Last modified however, might suffer from small cosmetic changes appearing as older posts. Last significant change might be something that could reasonably be determined automatically. (Documentation tried something similar, I think I remember.)

Comment: Not actually possible, look at my pictures, a hell of a lot of those old api questions were actually made very recently, not just updated.

Comment: @snb But some of the old api questions must be old, at least those you could get rid of. The only other alternative (API tagging) has been discussed by other answers.

Comment: "Modern" OpenGL (3.3+ core profile) is already 8 years old. But even nowadays a significant amount of OpenGL questions is about old OpenGL. This is to some amount caused by a lot of universities still teaching fixed function programming.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we add an `opengl-core` tag to stackoverflow? That solution wouldn't be perfect, but it would be a big step forward. Don't you think? Additionally, we could add a note to the `opengl` tag wiki to consider using the `opengl-core` tag instead.

Maybe we should deprecate the `opengl` tag, and add an `opengl-compat` and an `opengl-core` tag.

**Update:** I did read all the other answers. I read them before I wrote this one. The other answers explain why there can be no perfect solution, and conclude that we should do nothing to fix the problem. But I think that adding just one tag would solve 90% of the problem. I don't say this from a theoretical project management point of view: I worked with the OpenGL fixed function pipeline, and I worked with OpenGL Core 3.3, and so I know that the difference is so huge that they are really different APIs.

Comment: See the comments under NicolBolas's answer for that kind of discussion

Comment: @snb: yeah, I read them already. I still think that having an `opengl-core` tag is more useful than just keeping the status quo.

Answer (score 0):

Even if that has no chance to come live at any point (because it is impossible to force all users, specifically new ones, to abide to the discipline that would need), a generic solution to these kind of problems would be to add, for each question, a "metadata" section where the poster would add the version number of each software concerned in the question.

For example if it is about OpenGL version X on Windows version Y in C language variant Z using a compiler version R, then 4 piece of metadata would be attached to the question.

The metadata versions would be the exact versions used by the poster, no categories or broad groups here.

Search features would be built so that you would be able to filter on this metadata, including by groups (all 1.X versions of OpenGL, all 2.X versions of OpenGL, etc.).

And since you can not hope that users will always do that by themselves, some AI should try to infer the values from the content, and send things into review queues to be set properly. I see it as the same thing as editing the core of a question to make it readable.

This would solve a ton of problems at once, and remains orthogonal mostly to tags.

Sorry, that does not exist today nor maybe anytime, so no solution right now for you.

Comment: But what happens if such metadata and versioning isn't appropriate? For example, the greyscale question the OP talks about could have been asking about OpenGL 2.x, or higher ones. That is, that person's question could be answered with OpenGL 3.x or 4.x code; the code the asker provided as an example works on all versions of OpenGL. That the question doens't have a post-3.x solution is a matter of the age of the question, not the appropriateness of the answers. Do we want to categorize questions based on their current answers or on their questions?

Comment: The person would put the data related to what he is using. On SO it is about programming, hence you have a specific piece of code using specific software/libraries at specific versions. That does not forbid you replying for something using another version if you believe it is appropriate, it is just to be able to capture more information on the OP context, which is in question sometimes but having it aside as structured medatada would allow efficient search and operations on it.

Comment: "the code the asker provided as an example works on all versions of OpenGL." yet he is using only one specific version. And if he feels the version is irelevant he just does not put this at metadata. But I think it would be better to put all versions, even if you think not relevant, and deal with them later. If you want, it is akin of all these troubleshooting/bug reporting tools that first take a snapshot of what is installed to have a report with specific details on software and versions. Maybe the problem and solution will not depend on that, but you at least captured data formatted.

Comment: "*yet he is using only one specific version*" OpenGL doesn't work that way. Code that executes on 2.1 can also execute on 3.3 core profile. So if I'm asking a question, whose to say that I *don't* want an answer that works on 3.3?

Comment: You do not seem to read what I write...At the moment the code executes it executes with a specific version, no? That is the information to be recorded. That's all. You are reading far too much or too little in my proposition,but obviously not exactly what I did propose,or I phrased it poorly. Nobody says you do not/can not write an answer for version 3.3 if metadata says it's version 2.1. It is in that regard **exactly** as if the poster wrote in the text "I am using version 2.1". You do handle that info,or not, in your reply, as you wish. The metadata just adds **format** hence searchability.

Comment: "*Nobody says you do not/can not write an answer for version 3.3 if metadata says it's version 2.1.*" But if I did that, people looking for a 3.3 solution will not find my answer. That's what your metadata categorization is for; culling out searches for inappropriate versions.

Comment: Which is not true, as I specifically said that the metadata are on the question, not on the answers. This does not replace any other kind of search, it is an addition. Also the last thing I will say in that regard is that my proposition is **generic**, and not specific to OpenGL pecularities. It is just a way to record in a more structured format the context of the question, and use (or not) this data for better searches afterwards.